# How to use the super keyword in this code to call the constructor of the parent class?

Tags: java, constructor, super, default-constructor

I have seen various websites and ques for the super keyword and how it works, but I was not able to get my answer that

## how to use the super keyword to call the constructor of parent class

I have used the super in the first line of the constructor of child class (Actor).

```
{
  public String name, color;
  public int eyes, year;
  
  Person(String n, String c, int e, int y){
    name = n;
    color = c;
    eyes = e;
    year = y;
  }

}
class Actor extends Person
{
    String name, color;
    int eyes, year;
    
    Actor(String name,String color,int eyes,int year){
        super(String name, String color, int eyes, int year);
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        String str = String.format("The person %S is an Actor. He is %s in color, has %d eyes and debut in %d",name, color, eyes, year);
        return str;
    }

}
```

### This is giving me certain error :

```
/usercode/Main.java:20: error: ')' expected
        super(String name, String color, int eyes, int year);
                    ^
/usercode/Main.java:20: error: illegal start of expression
        super(String name, String color, int eyes, int year);
                         ^
/usercode/Main.java:20: error: ';' expected
        super(String name, String color, int eyes, int year);
                                 ^
/usercode/Main.java:20: error: not a statement
        super(String name, String color, int eyes, int year);
```

Comment: `super(name, color, eyes, year);`

Comment: don't use type when you call methods, or constructors `super(name, color, eyes, year);`

Comment: You do it the same way as shown in any guide / tutorial you can find on the web, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to call super in your case is `super(name, color, eyes, year)`.
Just like other methods, in the constructor signature (the line: `Actor(String name,String color,int eyes,int year){`) you should give the variable names and their types, but when calling a method you only give the variables (without the types). 'super' is just a call to another constructor (the father's one).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Helped a lot.